# finding multiple exact values using elastic search query

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I have inserted some data like below in elastic search. The data (name_list) looks like below.

```
{
  "manage": {
    "name_list": [
      {
        "name": "name1",
        "name_gr": ["gr1","gr2"]
      },
      {
        "name": "name2",
        "name_gr": ["gr1","gr2"]
      },
      {
        "name": "name3",
        "name_gr": ["gr2","gr3"]
      },
      {
        "name": "name4",
        "name_gr": ["gr1","gr2","gr3","gr4"]
      },
      {
        "name": "name4",
        "name_gr": ["gr4","gr5"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm trying to write a elastic search query using `elasticsearch_dsl` python module `Q`.

My simple query to get the names matching name_gr regexp -> gr.* looks like below :

```
{"query":{"regexp":{"name_gr":"gr.*"}}}
```

Query to get the name which has name_gr as "gr5" looks like:

```
{"query":{"regexp":{"name_gr":"gr5"}}}
```

Now, my question is : What should be my query if i want to get all the names which has name_gr as "gr1" and "gr2"?

For eg: Let's say my regexp for name_gr in this case will look like :

```
{"regexp":{"name_gr":"gr[12]"}}
```

Now, my result should contain names as `name1, name2 and name4` as name also contains both `gr1 and gr2.`

I don't know how do i form the query in this case, i think it i will contain  "must", "match". But no idea on how to form it.

Please help.

PS :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name_gr": "gr1"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "name_gr": "gr2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This query works, but my input can be a regexp, for eg: my input can be

gr[12], so my query should look something like this (syntax is wrong, which is to be fixed):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "regexp": {
              "name_gr": "gr[12]"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So, in this query above "match" portion should get internally resolved into ->

```
"must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "name_gr": "gr1"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "name_gr": "gr2"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
```

Comment: @aclokay can you please check this question?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what's there in your name_gr, I am assuming it has only one value, it may be anything (like: gr1, gr2, gr3...etc).

So in that case where **name_gr** has **gr1** or **gr2**:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name_gr": "gr1"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "name_gr": "gr2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If name_gr is a **list** then you query will look like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "regexp":{"name_gr":"gr.*"}
        },
        {
          "regexp":{"name_gr":"gr.*"}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check the edits. Input can be any regexp. In your's code should should be replaced with "must" and it's  not like name_gr is fixed as gr1 or gr2, it can be any regexp expression.

Comment: you can't assume name_gr has only one value, as indicvated in the question : name_gr is a list. and i want to pick those names which matches name_gr containing values which matches regexp : gr[12] or gr.*. It can be any regexp.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: why 2 times "regexp":{"name_gr":"gr.*"} this you have written? Regexp can be anything, it's not fixed how many times it will come. gr[12] was jus't an example. WHat if i have to do gr.*, no. of times "regexp":{"name_gr":"gr.*"} this is to be written we dont know.

Comment: Post your index mapping.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51411541/elastic-search-query-find-exact-match-of-values-in-the-list-from-regexp-input-pa

Comment: check this, i have re posted with better explanation