# Elastic search query find exact match of values in the list from regexp input parameter

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-dsl-py

My data looks like below:

```
  {
    "name": "name1",
    "name_gr": ["gr1","gr2"]
  },
  {
    "name": "name2",
    "name_gr": ["gr1","gr2"]
  },
  {
    "name": "name3",
    "name_gr": ["gr2","gr3"]
  },
  {
    "name": "name4",
    "name_gr": ["gr1","gr2","gr3","gr4"]
  },
  {
    "name": "name4",
    "name_gr": ["gr4","gr5"]
  }
```

Now, i am trying to write elastic search query using `elasticsearch_dsl` python module by importing `Q` from it.

My input query will be some `regex` on `"name_gr"`. For eg: `"name_gr": "gr[12]"`.
So, in this case I want all the names which has both "gr1" and "gr2" in their list of "name_gr".

So, the result for ->

Example 1 : `"name_gr": "gr[12]"` will be :

```
  {
    "name": "name1",
    "name_gr": ["gr1","gr2"]
  },
  {
    "name": "name2",
    "name_gr": ["gr1","gr2"]
  },
  {
    "name": "name4",
    "name_gr": ["gr1","gr2","gr3","gr4"]
  }
```

because, gr1 and gr2 both are present in name1, name2 and name4.

Example 2: `"name_gr": "gr.*"` will be :

```
  {
    "name": "name4",
    "name_gr": ["gr1","gr2","gr3","gr4"]
  }
```

because, all the gr's (gr1,gr2,gr3,gr4) are present in name4 only.

I tried writing my query like below:

```
must = [{'match':{'regexp': {'name_gr': 'gr[12]'}}}]
result = Q('bool', must = must)
```

But it gives name3 also in result, which is invalid as both gr1 and gr2 are not present in it. Please help. I am stuck in this from few days now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `match` query in your example where you want to be using `regexp` instead. To do this just use:

```
s = Search().query('regexp', name_gr='gr[12]')
s.execute()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you tell, how do i write the same thing if I am importing Q module this way: 
 from elasticsearch_dsl import Q  . Is this correct - Q('regexp', **{'name_gr': 'gr[12]'})  ?

Comment: Q is not a module, it is a function that will just construct the query, but it cannot actually be excuted, only `Search` can be executed. Using `Q` the syntax would be `Q('regexp', name_gr='gr[12]')` (the arguments to the `query` method are always passed to `Q` internally)

Comment: yes,that's correct. I have used exactly this Q('regexp', name_gr='gr[12]') . The problem is in the final result name3 is also coming. It should not come as name_gr list of name3 contains only gr2 not gr1.